# Interpreting Gaussian measurements in terms of information theory

Tags: statistics, information-theory, entropy, descriptive-statistics

I have a quantity that I want to measure, and I have obtained three sets of measurements A, B, and C, each represented by their mean $\mu_A$, $\mu_B$, $\mu_C$, and standard deviation $\sigma_A$, $\sigma_B$, $\sigma_C$, respectively. Assuming that the measurements follow a Gaussian distribution, I want to understand which set of measurements contains more information about the true value of the quantity being measured from an information theory perspective.

To give some context, let me provide numerical examples. Let's say that the true value of the quantity being measured is $x = 10$. Set A has measurements with mean $\mu_A = 9.9$ and $\sigma_A = 0.1$, set B has mean $\mu_B = 10$ and $\sigma_B = 1.0$, and set C mean $\mu_C = 8$ and $\sigma_C = 10$.

It's intuitive to say that it's set A due to the low standard deviation (assuming there's no bias), but how can I quantify the amount of information that each set of measurements provides about the true value (perhaps as $-\log_2 p(X)$)? Is there any way to compare the information content of the sets A, B, and C?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I gather that $A,B,C$ could be three different types of physical experiments which, according to their standard deviations have different precisions. Everyone would agree that $\mu_A$ is the best choice. It is hard to believe that any information theoretic formula could provide more insight into the problem than what you have achieved with those measurements. Keep it simple and transparent.

Comment: @KurtG. I agree! I'm asking this question in a broader context though. I want to be able to quantify the amount of information you lose, but assigning the wrong weights in a weighted average estimation, for example. It boils down to the question above, as the simplest example I could think of. In some situations, the uncertainty is estimated indirectly (though signal-to-noise ratio, for example) and those can be misleading. But misleading by how much?